# how to disable range slider thumbs while dragging if the difference b/w minValue and maxValue in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, seekbar, rangeslider

i want distance between the two thumbs ..like minage is 18 maxage is22 ditance 4...not like that come minage 18 maxage 18 no distance from two thumbs... but i want distance in thumbs

```
enter code here
 <com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
            android:id="@+id/ageSlider"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:valueFrom="18.0"
            android:valueTo="99.0"
            app:tickColor="#00000000"
            app:labelBehavior="gone"
            app:thumbColor="@color/white"
            app:thumbRadius="15dp"
            app:thumbStrokeColor="@color/profileview_font"
            app:thumbStrokeWidth="3.2dp"
            app:trackColorActive="@color/profileview_font"
            app:trackColorInactive="@color/trackcolor"
            app:trackHeight="3.2dp"
            app:values="@array/initial_slider_values" />
```

Comment: if the difference between what? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, please add a better description and perhaps also add what you already tried.

Comment: ok Robin, I ask to explain clearly

Answer (score 0):

In your `Activity` you can do this:

```kotlin
val rangeFinder = findViewById<RangeSlider>(R.id.ageSlider)

rangeFinder.addOnChangeListener { slider, value, from ->
    val (minAge, maxAge) = slider.values
    val difference = maxAge - minAge
}
```

Now the difference will contain the difference between the two values, so if `minAge` is `18` and `maxAge` is `22` the value shall be `4`